The error regarding to Opencensus Absinthe Plug. Traced_pipeline is undefined or private
I'm using the elixir version 1.15.8, erlang 25.3.2.12 and Phoenix.LiveDashboard.Router. Here is my router.ex
`pipeline :member_graphql do
    plug(Plug.Telemetry, event_prefix: [:myapp, :member_graphql_http])
    plug(:default_parser)
    plug(:fetch_session)
    plug(:accepts, ["json"])
    plug(MyApp.Authenticator, except: ["/graphql", "/member/graphql"])
end
scope "/member/graphql" do
    pipe_through(:member_graphql)
    post("/", Absinthe.Plug,
      schema: MyApp.Schema,
      json_codec: Jason,
      pipeline: {Opencensus.Absinthe.Plug, :traced_pipeline}
    )
end`

I got the error:
Request: POST /member/graphql
** (exit) an exception was raised:
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Opencensus.Absinthe.Plug.traced_pipeline/2 is undefined or private
(opencensus_absinthe 0.2.0) Opencensus.Absinthe.Plug.traced_pipeline
When I use elixir 1.14.5. It works fine. But elixir v1.15.8, it's failed.
Could you please give me idea or suggestion to fix this error.
